Alternative to accordions on mobile
I have the following page I am currently working on in a user portal for my company. The page displays information about household members of the user and some additional editable information about their household (in the accordions).
When we tested this design with users, they did not readily know how to interact with the accordions and it didn't seem like this was information they could view or edit.
What are some other ways to display their information and make it editable? Is presenting all information in view state flat without accordions a better option?


You could try adding an "Edit" button next to the title "Household members". Or you could display the information with labels (not inputs) and place an "edit" button next to those labels. Similar to "edit profile" experience in Instagram
